# How to test a contextual actionbar in junit

Tags: android, junit, android-contextmenu

I'm looking to test a contextual actionbar menu in JUnit.

1. I would like to test that the menu is correct.
2. Check that the drawables and text associated with the menu items are correct.
3. Launch the items.

How do I find the menu items to touch? Is it as simple as inflating the menu and finding the menu item and performing a `TouchUtils.clickView(this, view);`. I am uncertain.